# android check screen resolution

Tags: android, screen-resolution

i try to check screen resolution
i googled and i found one example,but i can not check screen resolution.i try check 480X800 and 720X1280 screen resolution

```
int screenSize = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
            & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;
    switch (screenSize) {
    case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE:

        mapimg.getLayoutParams().height = 400;

        break;
    case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL:

        mapimg.getLayoutParams().height = 200;
        break;
    case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL:

        break;
    default:
    }
```

**Layout**

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mapimages"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />

        <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/pointMap"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/mapimages"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" >
        </com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

this is a my code
i try to my imageview's height would be different in same screen resolution
in 480X800 height 200 and in 720X1280 400
when i run program in a both screen resolution  imageview has  200 height
what am i doing wrong? if anyone knows solution please help me
thanks

Comment: what about using different layout/dimension for different resolution and not doing this by code ...

Comment: @Selvin is offering a good solution: https://developer.android.com/samples/BasicSyncAdapter/res/values/dimen.html

Answer (score 0):

After setting parameters like height to a view that has already finished its [requestLayout()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestLayout()) pass, you need to again request for system to measure it. Do this at the end of switch statement:

```
mapimg.requestLayout();
```

Comment: i added it but nothink changed :(

Comment: @user3863447 could you show your entire code. I guess that you have wrap_content as the height and width in xml that could be messing with your view

Answer (score 0):

you can get the screen size like so:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

not if you are not doing this from an activity you can also do:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
```

Comment: thank you ,but i did not understand you how i can change image height in different screen size?

Comment: sorry guess i misunderstood your question

Comment: i want to my imageview's height must be 400 in large screen size(720X1280) and  200 height in normal screen size(480X800)

Comment: you can create different sizes of the image resource and store them all with the same name in the different drawable folders (one for each resolution)  you can also use dimension for height see: https://developer.android.com/samples/BasicSyncAdapter/res/values/dimen.html

Comment: thanks i know how to use different size of the images but at the moment i have only one size images

Comment: did you look at Dimens: https://developer.android.com/samples/BasicSyncAdapter/res/values/dimen.html

Answer (score 0):

use this code for get screen dp

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics ();
    display.getMetrics(outMetrics);
    float density  = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    float dpHeight = outMetrics.heightPixels / density;
    float dpWidth = outMetrics.widthPixels / density;
```

and set your image width and height with this line :

```
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
          dpWidth/2,dpHeight/2);
          image.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: thank you i will try it.but in your option what is a wrong in my source?i  have no idea what am i doing wrong